# Content type handler needs G-WAN restart

Tags: g-wan

I made a html.c content type handler to set max-age=99999999. 
At first, it works.
But when I amended it, saved it,
it didn't reflect the change until the G-WAN server is restarted.
Is it the designed behavior?
Updated:
add the code as below:

```
#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN exported functions

#define CACHE "Expires: Fri, May 02 2042 00:00:00 GMT\r\nCache-Control: max-age=99999999\r\n"  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   http_header(HEAD_ADD, CACHE, sizeof(CACHE) - 1, argv);
   //http_header(HEAD_AFTER, CACHE, sizeof(CACHE) - 1, argv);
   return 200;
}
```

pls advise whether i have done something wrong.

Comment: Please always post the relevant code section corresponding to your question.

Comment: It's not really related to the code, though... This sort of question and many more closed Gwan questions are more suited on [link](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Nagi, *serverfault* seems to like even less G-WAN questions than this site. Further, questions can be *moved* (from a site to another) by administrators rather than deleted or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

While `servlets` are reloaded on-the-fly, all `handlers` (connection handlers, content-type handlers, protocol handlers) are only reloaded once the program is stopped and restarted.

We initially thought that handlers are less likely to be modified than servlets. That may be change in a future version.